# Windows Form C# "MouseClick" event does not fire when clicking radio button

Tags: c#, winforms, events, click, radio-button

I am working with a windows form in which I have created a series of radiobuttons **programmaticaly**. I want to create an event that registers that one of these radios have been selected, and if so I enable the "OK" button.

I have my Event handler...

```
        protected void Checked_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is RadioButton)
            {
                RadioButton r = (RadioButton)c;
                if (r.Checked)
                {
                    this.OK.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

**But!!** the problem is **I do not seem to know what event I should be looking for to trigger this handler**.

I tried using the

- Click
- MouseClick
- MouseUp

  ```
          this.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Checked_Changed);
  ```

.. events but **it only works if i click on anything but the radiobuttons**.

I hope you guys can help me. Thanks a million, 
Jack.

Comment: Pretty vague, clearly you are doing it wrong.  The odds that "this.Click" is correct are very close to zero.  That sounds like the form's Click event,  subscribe the radio button's CheckChanged event instead.  All of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning your click event handler to the `Form`, not the radio buttons.

Here is an example of creating radio buttons programmatically and assigning an event handler.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create radio buttons
    RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton();
    RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton();
    RadioButton rb3 = new RadioButton();

    // Positioning on form
    rb1.Left = 10;
    rb2.Left = 10;
    rb3.Left = 10;
    rb1.Top = 10;
    rb2.Top = 30;
    rb3.Top = 50;

    // Assign event handler
    rb1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(RadioCheckChanged);
    rb2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(RadioCheckChanged);
    rb3.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(RadioCheckChanged);

    // Add to form
    this.Controls.Add(rb1);
    this.Controls.Add(rb2);
    this.Controls.Add(rb3);
}

private void RadioCheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Enable button here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `this.Click`, you need to use `this.radioButton.CheckedChanged` or `.Click` or whatever event you're using, otherwise you're subscribing the form, not the radiobutton

```
this.radioButton.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.Checked_Changed);
```